# Using linear algebra to solve differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble solving the following:
$$ dz_1/dt = z_1 + z_2 $$
$$ dz_2/dt = z_2 $$

The matrix corresponding to that is:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\\ z_2 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} dz_1/dt \\\ dz_2/dt \end{pmatrix}$$

I know the answer will be using the form $$ dz/dt = Ave^{\lambda} + ... $$, where v is the eigenvector for each eigenvalue \lambda.

I then try to set that matrix determinant minus eigenvalue to be 0:
$$(A-I*\lambda) =  \begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda & 1\\\ 0 & 1-\lambda\end{pmatrix}$$

Using that the determinant of that matrix being equal zero lets us find the eigenvalue, I solve for that:
$$ ((1 - \lambda)^2 - 1*0) = 0 => \lambda = 1$$

Putting that in the matrix to get the eigenvector, I get:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} = (0, 0, 0) $$

With all the 0's and just one 1 in the matrix, how do I solve for the eigenvector from there?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just first solve $z_2'(t)=z_2(t)$, i.e. your second equation, as it's independent of $z_1$, and then use that to solve the first equation?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this system easily  via the matrix exponential, $$z(t)=e^{tA}z(0).$$
Here we have $A=I+N$, $N^2=0$, so that the exponential has the reduced formula
$$
e^{tA}=e^t·e^{tN}=e^t(I+tN)
$$

Answer (score 0):

It not need be that hard.

The method you are using comes in handy when you have a lot of difficult systems to solve. The system you are trying to solve can be taken care of using simpler by-hand-methods due to the fact that the equations are both first order and thus can be solved immediately.

Let's start by solving the second equation. We could do this because we have just the two functions without the independent variable. So it's trivial to solve because we know the solution right away
\begin{align}
z_2^{'}(t) - z_2 (t) = 0 &\implies z_2(t) = e^{- \int-1dt} \left[ c_1 + \int 0 dt \right]\\
&\implies \boxed{z_2(t) = c_1 e^{t}}.
\end{align}

Now that we know the second function, we can just plug it in in the first equation and solve it. Since it's first order, we can solve it trivially:
\begin{align}
z_1^{'}(t) - z_1(t) = c_1 e^t &\implies z_1(t) = e^{- \int -1dt} \left[c_2 + \int c_1 e^{t} e^{\int-dt} dt\right]\\
&\implies z_1(t) = e^t \left[ c_2 + \int c_1dt \right]\\
&\implies \boxed{z_1(t) = e^{t} \left\{ c_2 + t c_1 \right\}},
\end{align}
and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable so you can't use your approach. The best you can do (as it is triangular) is to first solve the  equation corresponding to the last row of the matrix (the easiest one $z_2' = z_2$), and then the first row $z_1'=z_1+z_2$ when you already know $z_2$.

Answer (score 0):

I shall give you my input. Instead of solving the ODE individually as what the others recommended, we shall retain the use of matrices and vectors. So building onto what you have provided, we can express the equations above in state-space representation, in the form $\dot{z} = Az$.

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
   \dot{z_1}  \\
   \dot{z_2}  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
   z_1  \\
   z_2  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

From the eigenvalues you found, we can see that $\lambda = 1$ is of multiplicity 2. We will have to apply the Jordan normal form. So, $A$ can be decomposed to $A = QJQ^{-1}$, where $Q$ consists of your (generalized) eigenvectors and $J$ consists of your Jordan block.

An intuitive way to find our eigenvectors $q_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is to compute:

$$
q_i =
\begin{bmatrix} 
   -a_{12}  \\
   a_{11} - \lambda_i  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
given
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For $\lambda = 1$, the eigenvector:
$$
q_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1  \\
0  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To find the other eigenvector $q_2$, it must satisfy:
$$
(A-I)q_2 = q_1 \\
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1\\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}  
$$
We can choose:
$$
q_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0  \\
-1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$q_2$ is also known as our generalized eigenvector.

Hence:
$$
Q = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix},
J = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, we can solve our $2 \times 2$ system of linear ODE by computing:
$$
\begin{align}
z & = e^{At}z_0 \\
 & = Qe^{Jt}Q^{-1}z_0 \\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
z_1  \\
z_2  \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
e^t & te^t  \\
0 & e^t  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
z_{01}  \\
z_{02}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
e^t & te^t  \\
0 & e^t  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
z_{01}  \\
z_{02}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
=
z_{01}e^t
\begin{bmatrix} 
1  \\
0  \\
\end{bmatrix} +
z_{02}e^t
\begin{bmatrix} 
t  \\
1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $z_0$ is the vector consisting of the entries of the integration constants $z_{01}$ and $z_{02}$.

Hope it helps!